# Бронирование мест в кинотеатре (кнопки)

Tags: android

Добрый день, возникла потребность в создании функции бронирования мест в кинотеатре через отображение схемы зала.

Пример:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я новичок в андроид разработке, знаю как отрисовать места через canvas, но не пойму как на эти "кнопки" повесить обработчики нажатий?

Поделитесь опытом, как лучше реализовать эту задумку. Заранее благодарю.

Comment: Новичок? и что? А ты сам пробовал сделать ? Покажи что пробовал сам и где не получилось.

Comment: Вопрос не в том что у меня что то не работает, я банально не знаю как это реализовано. Через canvas как я понял обработчик так просто не повесить, а создавать сотню батонов на мой взгляд неэффективно

Answer (score 1):

Я бы все таки для начала реализовал бы это через стандартные кнопки и посмотрел как оно будет работать - это не займет много времени.
Точнее даже не кнопки а свои виджеты наследуемые от View. Добавлять их на экран естественно динамически и навесить на всех один обработчик, а не на каждую отдельный.

Это в самом простом случае но мне кажется этого будет достаточно по производительности и функционалу.

Если хотите нарисовать на канвасе - пожалуйста, это не сложно - надо сделать кастомный компонент, наследуемый от `View`. В любом случае у вас будет массив (двумерный видимо) объектов к примеру скажем PlaceButton - одно место в зале, у которого будут координаты, размеры и состояние нажата/отжата - рассчитываете размеры исходя из размеров родительского компонента.

Для отрисовки можно использовать класс `Drawable`, см. его методы `setBounds` и `draw`.

Обработка нажатий тоже выполняется просто - переопределяете `onTouchEvent` , там вам приходит `MotionEvent` с координатами куда коснулись. - по ним можно рассчитать по какой PlaceButton нажали. Ну или в самом простом случае пробежаться по массиву и спросить у каждого "не принадлежат ли тебе эти координаты?", если да, то изменить состояние и перерисовать.

Answer (score 0):

Сделай так, что каждое место - отдельный canvas, добавь к каждому слушателя.

Comment: И чем же такой вариант будет отличаться от создания кнопки на каждое место, от которого хочет уйти автор вопроса?

Comment: Кнопок под сотню делать это возможно, но на мой взгляд очень глупо